# Assim que edito o registro, todos os que já tinham são substituídos pelo editado. Onde errei?

Tags: php

```
<script>
var apagar = {
    sim:function(id){
        if(confirm('Tem certeza que deseja apagar ?')){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'pagina/<?php echo $url; ?>/apagar/'+id,
                data:{'id':id},
                success:function(html){
                    alert('Apagado com sucesso!');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['tipo']) && $_GET['tipo'] == 'editar'){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $item_ver = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM loja WHERE id='".$id."'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($_POST){
        $item = $_POST['item'];
        $valor = $_POST['valor'];
        $vendedor = $_POST['vendedor'];
        $vendido = $_POST['vendido'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        if(empty($item) || empty($valor) || empty($vendedor)){
            echo Site::Alerta('Preencha todos campos!',false);
        }else{
            $inserir = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE loja SET item=:item, valor=:valor, vendedor=:vendedor, vendido=:vendido, status=:status");
            $inserir->bindParam(':item',$item);
            $inserir->bindParam(':valor',$valor);
            $inserir->bindParam(':vendedor',$vendedor);
            $inserir->bindParam(':vendido',$vendido);
            $inserir->bindParam(':status',$status);
            $inserir->execute();
            echo Site::Alerta('Editado com sucesso!','pagina/'.$url);
       }
    }
?>
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    Item:<br>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="item" value="<?php echo $item_ver['item']; ?>"><br>
    Valor:<br>
    <input type="number" min="1" class="text" name="valor" value="<?php echo $item_ver['valor']; ?>"><br>
    Vendedor:<br>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="vendedor" value="<?php echo $item_ver['vendedor']; ?>"><br>
    Vendido:<br>
    <select name="vendido" class="select">
        <option value="true" <?php if($item_ver['vendido'] == 'true'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Sim</option>
        <option value="false" <?php if($item_ver['vendido'] == 'false'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>N達o</option>
    </select><br>
    Status:<br>
    <select name="status" class="select">
        <option value="true" <?php if($item_ver['status'] == 'true'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Ativo</option>
        <option value="false" <?php if($item_ver['status'] == 'false'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Inativo</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Editar">
</form>
<?php
}else if(isset($_GET['tipo']) && $_GET['tipo'] == 'apagar'){
        $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
        $delete = $pdo->query("DELETE FROM loja WHERE id='$id'");
        echo 1;
}else{
    if($_POST){
        $item = $_POST['item'];
        $valor = $_POST['valor'];
        $vendedor = $_POST['vendedor'];
        if(empty($item) || empty($valor) || empty($vendedor)){
            echo Site::Alerta('Preencha todos campos!',false);
        }else{
            $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO loja(item, valor, vendedor, vendido, time, status) VALUES(:item, :valor, :vendedor, 'false', '".$time."', 'true')");
            $inserir->bindParam(':item',$item);
            $inserir->bindParam(':valor',$valor);
            $inserir->bindParam(':vendedor',$vendedor);
            $inserir->execute();
            echo Site::Alerta('Inserido com sucesso!','pagina/'.$url);
       }
    }
?>
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    Item:<br>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="item"><br>
    Valor:<br>
    <input type="number" min="1" class="text" name="valor"><br>
    Vendedor:<br>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="vendedor"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Criar">
</form>
<table width="100%" style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; float:left">
    <tr style="height: 40px;">
        <th><img src="assets/img/x.png"></th>
        <th><img src="assets/img/editar.png"></th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Vendedor</th>
        <th>Vendido</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM loja ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($ver = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $css = $i%2==0 ? '' : 'background: #EEE;';
    ?>
    <tr style="height: 40px; <?php echo $css;?>">
        <th><a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="apagar.sim('<?php echo $ver['id']; ?>')"><img src="assets/img/x.png"></a></th>
        <th><a href="pagina/<?php echo $url; ?>/editar/<?php echo $ver['id']; ?>"><img src="assets/img/editar.png"></a></th>
        <th><?php echo $ver['item']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ver['valor']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ver['vendedor']; ?></th>
        <th><?php if($ver['vendido'] == 'true'){ echo 'Sim'; }else{ echo 'N達o'; }; ?></th>
        <th><?php if($ver['status'] == 'true'){ echo 'Ativo'; }else{ echo 'Inativo'; }; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++;} ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: A ausência do `WHERE` é um erro muito comum, e que causa muitos danos. Tente não esquecer.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Seu error está no seu sql:

```
UPDATE loja SET item=:item, valor=:valor, vendedor=:vendedor, vendido=:vendido, status=:status
```

O correto seria:

```
 UPDATE loja SET item=:item, valor=:valor, vendedor=:vendedor, vendido=:vendido, status=:status **WHERE id=:id**
```

Com isso você consegue alterar apenas um registro em questão, se você não fizer isso, toda a tabela **LOJA** será alterada para o novo valor passado em questão.